# Bzr fast-export return bzr: broken pipe

Tags: git, bazaar, git-fast-import

I need to export my bzr repo to git. To do this i'm trying to use `bzr fast-export --git-branch=mybranch --plain | git fast-import --force`.
The bzr starts to run but stops and return an error:

```
15:11:58 Calculating the revisions to include ... 
15:11:58 Starting export of 8961 revisions ... 
15:12:17 1000/8961 commits exported at 3155/minute  
15:12:30 2000/8961 commits exported at 3718/minute  
15:13:12 3000/8961 commits exported at 2421/minute  
fatal: Path data/sql/patch-02-27.sql not in branch 
fast-import: dumping crash report to .git/fast_import_crash_4632
bzr: broken pipe
```

Someone help me! Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need the `--plain` there? What if you run without?

Comment: It does look like your repository might have a corruption of some kind. Could you run the actions separately?

Comment: you do need the --plain, otherwise git-fast-import might complain about output from bzr-fastexport it doesn't understand. E.g. bzr supports multiple authors for each commit, git doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience fast-import/fast-export can fail due to out of memory.

This tends to happen when large binary files are present.

This has long been raised as an issue, but last time I remember checking (~september 2010) it didn't look like it was going to be addressed. At one time, I wasn't able to migrate my bazaar repository *with history* to git because of this.

I believe I may later managed to do so by switching to a 64 bit distribution.